# Too much execution inside the Application onCreate()

Tags: android, performance

This is rather an academic question: If I was to put a lot of processing inside the `onCreate()` method of the `Application` class, what's there to stop it?

By doing this, don't I gain the power to slow down the user's device? Is there something Android OS can do to prevent/stop it?

Comment: there is such a thing called `ANR` (Application Not Responding). The dialog prompting user to force-stop the app appears once your app blocks UI thread for certain amount of time.

Comment: it's more your own design. You can do heavy work in async task and display some nice loading indicator, you can use splash screen to do heavy initialization and redirect to the actual activity.